# "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2": What does the terminal property of the Route interface do?

Tags: angular, routes, beta

Within the Angular2 3.0.0-beta.2 Router there is a property called `terminal` for which I cannot find documentation. What does this property do?

See source file: `@angular/router/src/config.d.ts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`terminal` was used to match empty `('')` routes like this for example:

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/crisis-center',
  terminal: false
},
```

However since 3.0.0-beta.1 it has been [changed](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/CHANGELOG.md) to `pathMatch`, which is documented: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html (or jump directly to where [redirects](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect) are discussed)